# In modern logic, why does "All S is P" contradict "Some S is not P"?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic, syllogism

In modern logic, the existential import is removed from universal statements. So All S is P may still be true if there is no S at all.

Contradictory statements must have opposite truth values.

Why is the contradictory relationship between "All S is P" and "Some S is not P" in modern logic?

There are 2 cases, one where there is at least one object that is S, one where there isn't.

If there isn't an object that is S, then "Some S is not P" must be false, because it implies the existence of at least one object that is S and not P.
But in a world without S, "All S is P" doesn't have to be true. It is conceivable that it is false too. Doesn't this mean there is one case where both statements are false?

Comment: Why do you think it is possible that "All S is P" can be false if there are no objects which are S? (It isn't.)

Answer (score 3):

Why in modern logic:

> does “All S is P” contradict “Some S is not P”?

Because “All S is P” is **∀x(Sx → Px)**; negating it, we get: **¬∀x(Sx → Px)**.

Due to equivalence between **¬∀** and **∃¬**, this in turn is equivalent to:

> **∃x¬(Sx → Px)**.

Now, in propositional logic, **¬(R → Q)** is equivalent to: **(R & ¬Q)**, and thus we finally get:

> > **∃x(Sx & ¬Px)**.

Thus, negating “All S is P” we have obtained: “Some S is not P”.

---

What happens if there isn't an object that is **S** ? Obviously, "Some S is not P" is false, because **∃x(Sx & ¬Px)** is false.

But "All S is P" is true, because it is **∀x(Sx → Px)** and a *conditional* with a *false* antecedent is *true*.

If there are no **S**s, then **Sx → Px** is *true* for any possible value of **x**, and thus **∀x(Sx → Px)** is true.

Answer (score 2):

In a world without S, "All S is P" is **true**. You must keep in mind how it is formulated in first-order logic:

> ∀x(Sx→Px)

Since there are no S things, the implication is always (vacuously) true.

So there's no case in which "All S is P" and "Some S is not P" are both false.